# How to use variables in cite

Tags: bibtex, citing, ieeetran

I have some citation keys in text files that I'm reading, I am able to read successfully the keys and print them in the article but not inside a `\cite{\MyVariable}`.

In particular, this is what I am trying to achieve `\cite{\CitePointer}` (from the current example) and `\CitePointer` has the bib key I need to reference.

Here you have a complete working example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-tags.tex}
Hello world I have a tag inside this
\iffalse
%<*tag:citekey>
IEEEhowto
%</tag:citekey>
\fi
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

- This is working as expected\cite{IEEEhowto}

\edef\PaperCiteRef{IEEEhowto}
- This reference is working as expected we will call \PaperCiteRef \ in a cite\cite{\PaperCiteRef}

\edef\CitePointer{\ExecuteMetaData[\jobname-tags.tex]{tag:citekey}}
- This prints the reference key \CitePointer 

- The following is not working (uncomment it)
%- Why this \cite{\CitePointer} wont work?

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
        \bibitem{IEEEhowto}
        H.~Kopka and P.~W. Daly, \emph{A Guide to \LaTeX}, 3rd~ed.\hskip 1em plus
        0.5em minus 0.4em\relax Harlow, England: Addison-Wesley, 1999.
\end{thebibliography}
    
\end{document}
```

I suppose that `\CitePointer` is coming with some formating that breaks the `\cite` command but I am not able to fix it, any ideas?

In this case `\cite{\PaperCiteRef}` works but `\cite{\CitePointer}` isn't.

Comment: it is a very bad idea to write with filecontents over \jobname.tex and I have some doubts that you actually tried that. Your \edef does nothing sensible, try `\show\CitePointer` to see what your command actually then contains.

Comment: The filecontents is just an example for the inline file, I have them separated in multiple files and used with \ExecuteMetaData

Comment: sure, but it would have worked (which it happily didn't)  it would have overwritten the main file.

Comment: Uupps yup it will behave better now with the edits from @egreg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `\edef\CitePointer{\ExecuteMetaData[\jobname-tags.tex]{tag:citekey}}` doesn't define `\CitePointer` to the string you'd like to. Indeed, if I add

```
\show\CitePointer
```

after that instruction I get

```
> \CitePointer=macro:
->\ExecuteMetaData [camacho-tags.tex]{tag:citekey}.
```

(because I called the main file `camacho.tex`). You should use `\CatchFileBetweenTags` instead.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-tags.tex}
Hello world I have a tag inside this
\iffalse
%<*tag:citekey>
IEEEhowto
%</tag:citekey>
\fi
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

-- This is working as expected~\cite{IEEEhowto}

\edef\PaperCiteRef{IEEEhowto}
-- This reference is working as expected we will call \PaperCiteRef \ in a 
   cite~\cite{\PaperCiteRef}

\CatchFileBetweenTags{\CitePointer}{\jobname-tags.tex}{tag:citekey}
-- This prints the reference key \CitePointer\ and the reference
   works~\cite{\CitePointer}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{IEEEhowto}
  H.~Kopka and P.~W. Daly, \emph{A Guide to \LaTeX}, 3rd~ed.%
  \hspace{1em plus 0.5em minus 0.4em}Harlow, England: Addison-Wesley, 1999.

\end{thebibliography}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm, one side note, do you know if there is a macro I can use that will process what the variable has before actually adding it to the doc? Something like \cite{\RenderThis{\CitePointer}} (from my example)

Comment: @ccamacho Sorry, but I don't understand the question.

Comment: No worries :) there is no need to overcomplicate this, thanks for the help!!